# Равные и пропорциональные отступы между ссылками CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, адаптивная-верстка

```
   <div class="header"> 
    <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка1</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка1</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка1</a>
   </div>
```

Нужно задать равный и пропорциональный размерам страницы отступ между ссылками и окном браузера. Также нужно чтобы все это было адаптивным.

Comment: Нужно? Задайте .... В чем именно вы видите проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.header{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.header a{
  /*Чтобы ничего не слиплось*/
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка1</a>
  <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка1</a>
  <a href="" target="_blank">ссылка2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Только для адаптивности я изменил пиксели на нужное число %.

Comment: Да не за что. Я бы, кстати, не советовал задавать поля и отступы(особенно вертикальные) в процентах.